# Is the following a decreasing function? And can it be formally shown?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, summation

Suppose $x, y > 1$. Is the following function decreasing in $x$?

$f(x) = \displaystyle\int_x^{xy} \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{2}{(z+n)(2z+2n+1)} \mathrm{d}z$

I know how to take the derivative, but I'm not sure where to proceed from there, given that it leads to an infinite sum. Thank you for your help!

Comment: hint: the sum equals $\log(\Gamma(z+1/2)/\Gamma(z))'$.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental theorem of calculus write $$F=\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{x y} f(z) \, dz=y f(x y)-f(x)$$ Now $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{2}{(z+n)(2z+2n+1)}=2 \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}(z)\right)$$ (where appears the digamma funtion) and this is a decreasing function of $z$.

So,

- if $y<1$, $F$ increases
- if $y=1$, $F=0$
- if $y>1$, $F$ decreases

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm not quite sure I understand your argument. Given that $\psi^{(0)}$ is increasing when $z > 1$, I want to show that $yf(xy) < f(x)$ for any $x, y >1$ to show that the original function is decreasing. Does the fact that f(z) is decreasing in $z$ help me to do this?